# Reload aliases on change automatically without closing the shell window

Tags: zsh

I have my aliases stored in `~/.zsh_aliases` and sourced in `~/.zshrc`:

```
# Access custom aliases in the shell
[ -e "${HOME}/.zsh_aliases" ] && source "${HOME}/.zsh_aliases"
```

However, when changing the name of an alias, I have to always close the current shell window and open a new one for the change to become active.

Can Zsh automatically reload aliases on change to make them available without having to close the shell window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not actually need to close and reopen your terminal for that, just running `source ~/.zsh_aliases` (loads the new and changed aliases) or maybe `exec zsh` (replaces the current shell with a new one) would work, too.

If you really want to re-source `~/.zsh_aliases` whenever it is modified, I would suggest adding the following to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
# File containing aliases; 
ALIAS_FILE="${HOME}/.zsh_aliases

reload_aliases () {
    # do nothing if there is no $ALIAS_FILE
    [[ -e ALIAS_FILE ]] || return 1
    # check if $ALIAS_FILE has been modified since last reload
    # the modifier `(:A)` resolves any symbolic links
    if [[ $LAST_ALIAS_RELOAD < $(stat -c %Y ${ALIAS_FILE}(:A)) ]]; then
        # remove all aliases; optional!
        # only do this if all of your aliases are defined in $ALIAS_FILE
        # also affects aliases defined on the command line
        unalias -m '*'
        # load aliases
        source $ALIAS_FILE
        # update date of last reload
        LAST_ALIAS_RELOAD=$(date +%s)
    fi
}

# make reload_aliases to be run before each prompt
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd reload_aliases
```

Note, that any changes will only be available on a new prompt. That means, if you modify `~/.zsh_aliases`, you need to press at least <kbd>Enter</kbd> once in the all terminals for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Many Thanks @Adaephon! It does not work yet. Does it have to be `autotoload`? I get a `command not found` error. Changing it to `autoload` does not make it work either.

Comment: You are of course correct, it needs to be `autoload`. Aside from that, it should work, at least it does for me. What happens if you start a zsh with your old configuration and just copy past the above code onto the command line? (You might need to remove the comments or run `setopt interactivecomments` for that beforehand)

Comment: I tried it but it does not work either. Can you please have a look at my [~/.zshrc](https://gist.github.com/orschiro/f51b4257be9f632d56d7)?

Comment: I tested your `~/.zshrc` and everything looks fine. Which version of zsh are you using? You could add `print "reloading"` as the first line to `reload_aliases()` just to see if the function is actually run. If not, does it work if you write `precmd () { reload_aliases; }` instead of the last two lines in my code snippet?

Comment: `reloading` is shown! So the function is called. But the aliases just not reloaded for some reasons. Installed version: `zsh 5.0.7-1`.

Comment: Is it also shown if you put it inside the `if`-block? If not, please check the outputs of `echo $LAST_ALIAS_RELOAD` and `stat -c %Y $ALIAS_FILE`. Does either change after you edit `~/.zsh_aliases`?

Comment: It is not shown when put inside the `if`-block. `echo $LAST_ALIAS_RELOAD = 1422200835` & `stat -c %Y $ALIAS_FILE = 
1398936795`

Comment: The return value of `stat` would indicate that `$ALIAS_FILE` has not been modified since May, 1st 2014. Either you are not editing `$ALIAS_FILE` or for some reason the modification date is not set when you do so. The first one could be due to a typo in the name or maybe `${HOME}` is not what it should be. I have no idea what could cause the later one…

Comment: I found the issue! It is because I am symlinking my alias_file: `.zsh_aliases -> Dotfiles/zsh/.zsh_aliases`. Thus, the following works: `ALIAS_FILE="${HOME}/GoogleDrive/Dotfiles/zsh/.zsh_aliases"`. But then [fasd](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/tree/master/modules/fasd) autocompletion feature breaks...

Comment: I do not use `fasd` (or even `prezto`), so I cannot check for that. But if I had to guess I would say it is probably the `unalias -m '*'` line causing that. Try if if works without that line.

Comment: With the uncommented `unalias -m '*'` it does finally work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I use an alias, thusly: -

```
alias vialias='vi ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/alias.zsh ; source ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/alias.zsh'
```

When I run vialias, I edit my aliases, then when I leave vi, the change(s) take effect.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify the accepted answer *add*:

```
source ~/.zsh_aliases
```

in the `~/.zshrc` below the *plugins* section.

Then *add* an alias inside the `~/.zsh_aliases` like so:

```
alias f="exec zsh"
```

To refresh zsh & aliases type `f`